# Writing SQL table directly to file in Scala

Tags: scala, export-to-csv, azure-databricks

Team,
I'm working on Azure databricks, I'm able to write a dataframe to CSV file using the following option:

```
df2018JanAgg
.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.save("dbfs:/FileStore/output/df2018janAgg.csv")
```

but I'm seeking an option to write data directly from SQL table to CSV in Scala.
Can someone please let me know if such options exist.

Thanks,
Srini

Answer (score 0):

Yes data could be directly loaded between a sql table to Datafame and vice-versa. Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

```
//JDBC -> DataFarme -> CSV
spark.read
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
.option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.load()
.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.save("dbfs:/FileStore/output/df2018janAgg.csv")

//DataFarme -> JDBC
df.write
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
.option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.save()
```

Comment: Thanks @hagarwal. I know writing etween Dataframe and SQL. I'm looking for direct option to write SQL table to output CSVfile instead of writing SQL table to Dataframe and then to output CSV. Please let me know if there is an option